# Facing problems with openERP ORM methods

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

I am facing problem in module development, I develop a complete student with name and degree so far  and successfully shown on web. 
Now when I am going toward using ORM methods, I am unable to understand how it works and from where ids etc come, like I want to fetch all students from my database table `STUDENT`.

Kindly guide me how I have to play with ORM methods with simple example, it will be helpful if someone can upload their module with simple ORM methods example.

Comment: How did you develop `student` module if you now nothing about ORM? It would be nice if you posted what you did right now.

Comment: i just made a student class with name , registration# etc and show that one on web , i just start learning openerp so for the time being i just learn class defination and how to show on web through XML so next i am going to learn ORM

Answer (score 1):

The two main ORM methods for finding records are search and name_search (name_search is just search with some preset search parameters).

The search method only returns IDs that you then use in a browse to get the records so a very common pattern is this:

```
student_ids = self.search(cr, uid, [('grade', '=', 'A'), ('enrolled', '=', True), ('gpa', '>=', 4.0), ('course.department', '=', 'Science')] context = context
students = self.browse(cr, uid, student_ids, context = context)
```

The slightly tricky part of the search is the list of search parameters. These are lists of tuples that are field, operator, value.  There is an implicit AND here so you need to use '|' if you want ORs.  Note that it will handle related objects, I used course.department in the example.

The search method will return a list of IDs or an empty list.  Note how  you can just pass it into the browse method without testing it because the browse method will return a list of browse records for each id in the list so if you pass in an empty list of IDs you get an empty list of browse records back.

Have a look at https://doc.openerp.com/trunk/server/api_models/

Comment: Thank you adrian for answering the question in a nice way ,,,,
but my problem is when i call my fuction with following parameters

obj = open_partners()

obj.get_result_info(cr, uid, 'res.partner', [('id', '=', 140)] , context=None)

it show error for cr and uid and said global name cr and uid undefinded . thats the main error

i will grateful if can help regards

Comment: That is a python problem, not an OpenERP specific one.  You are trying to call your method with two arguments that you don't currently have.  You would need to post your source code to be able to advise on that one.

Comment: class Sale(osv.osv):

    _name = 'sale'


    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Company Name', size=128)
    }


    def get_default_company(self, cr, uid, context=None):
        company_id = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid).company_id.id,
        return company_id


Sale()

this is source code , just tell me how to call the method , get_default_company() .

Comment: You are not far off.  Your default method should return company name, not id and you just define a defaults dictionary after the method definition.  Note you set the default to the callable, not the result of the callable, OpenERP will take care of the arguments for you.  One question though, are you sure you want to store the company name as a char field?  Normally you would use a many2one to res.company and OpenERP will display the company name anyway.  Default definition is _defaults = {'name': get_default_company}